# How do I code a dynamic website?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

Never mind. I've found the correct answer

Comment: may you can learn cms before, like wordpress.

Comment: Search for 'write a CMS tutorial' or 'write a blog tutorial'; include the desired language (PHP?) in the searches. There are many different concepts - such as storing and retrieving the data from the server (PHP, AJAX, SQL, whatever) and rendering the output (HTML, CSS, JavaScript, templates, whatever). Following allow with a (good) tutorial will at least help get some of the infrastructure setup.

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: I'm surprised that this question hasn't been riddled with down votes and close votes.. let alone having 3 answers?  Wow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you have already all pieces in front of you, but don't know where to start.

I suggest that you

- find an exciting Bootstrap blog template (like the free ones at [Start Bootstrap](http://startbootstrap.com))
- understand the code, which is usually a good mixture of HTML5, CSS3, JavaScript with a modest use of jQuery
- tweak it with your own ideas
- if you have some special needs not covered by the template (for example collapsible menu items), you can browse the [Bootply Snippet Library](http://www.bootply.com) to look how others coded it.

Nowadays no web programmer starts from scratch. They choose a template with the basic structure of a one-pager, multi-pager, blog, e-commerce, etc. and start from there.

By the way: **Alaboudi** mentioned in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34959379/5825093) that you need to learn MySQL, too. This is indeed needed for dynamic content like e-commerce and blogs, but not for static content like business websites that don't change that often, but put an emphasis on individual page layouts.

But to get your first website up fast I would start with static websites and later extend your knowledge to MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

Everything you have learnt is great, but you must also learn a database querying language (SQL). May I suggest you start learning MySQL, its very friendly for beginners. Now let me give you an example of how to code a dynamic website.

Lets consider facebook profile pages as an example. Firstly you must realize that there isnt 1 billion uniquely saved profile pages made for each user on the server. Rather, there is only 1 html css template that is filled in with appropriate information depending on the person loading the page. When the visitor comes to his profile page, his information must be queried from the database using a backend language (PHP in your case). Once the result of the call is retrieved, you fill in the appropriate information in your html (name, age, friends, blah, blah) and send it over to the user. So technically you are constructing the complete page with every call and you never actually have the complete page saved on the server.

Long story short, you should look into using a database.

Answer (score -1):

This is not really a question. I would suggest you to go and code something.

You want to do a blog? Ok, try to do it with what you've learned so far.

When you'll start to build it, you'll have specific questions on specific problems, you can then search on Google your specific problem or come back to StackOverflow and ask for it.

Any resource is good and lucky you, there are plenty of resources on the internet ;)

Comment: He is a user thats just starting @PeterPan666. and if you read his question, you would have noticed that this user does not know of databases and their functionality. I consider his question to be correct. I just think you have forgotten of the times of when you started out.

Comment: Well in fact I started just like him and with what I just said. IMO he has read/saw enough documentation, now it's time to just do something. In my case, when I started, I could read an entire documentation about a framework but until I've done something with it, it was impossible for me to remember anything.